# In ReactJS, how do I render one component within another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a ReactJS app, and want to show a landing page which displays either a Sign In form or a Register form, depending on which link was followed.

So far, my App component looks like this:

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path={ROUTES.LANDING}  render={(props) => <LandingPage {...props} subPage={SignInPage} />}/>
      <Route path={ROUTES.SIGNIN}   render={(props) => <LandingPage {...props} subPage={SignInPage} />}/>
      <Route path={ROUTES.REGISTER} render={(props) => <LandingPage {...props} subPage={RegisterPage} />}/>
      <Route render={(props) => <LandingPage {...props} subPage={SignInPage} />}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Now, I'm not sure how to get the actual sub-pages to show within the landing page.

In my landingpage component, I have this:

```
class LandingPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {props}

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div>{this.state.subPage}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LandingPage;
```

but it doesn't show anything when I go to 'landingpage/signin'.  I can see in the console that this.state.subPage contains the correct component, and when I change the Route to show the SignInPage directly, that works fine, so the SignInPage is definitely working ok on its own.

My SignInPage component contains:

```
const SignInPage = () => (
  <div>
    <p>Sign In</p>
    <SignInForm />
  </div>
);

class SignInFormBase extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  onSubmit = event => {
    // This will handle form submission
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
        <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
const SignInForm = compose(
  withRouter,
  withFirebase,
)(SignInFormBase);

export default SignInPage;

export { SignInForm };
```

I'm guessing that maybe the issue is that SignInForm is a component but SignInPage isn't? But I'm new to React, so I don't know how to reconfigure them!

What can I try next?

Comment: You can also render `<LandingPage ...><SignInPage /></LandingPage>` then do `{this.props.children}` in your JSX.

Comment: Thank you.  That's good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing the `subPage` to the `LandingPage` as props, you can take that component from props and render it like below

```
class LandingPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  render() {
    const SubPage = this.props.subPage;
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div><SubPage /></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LandingPage;
```

NOTE: You don't need to copy props into state

Comment: Thank you!  That's very helpful.  I've tried it and it works, so thank you very much!

Comment: (I've accepted this as correct answer because it's the one I used, but the other solutions seem to work as well)

Answer (score 1):

In App component:

```
<Route render={(props) => <LandingPage {...props}><SignInPage /></LandingPage>}/>
```

In landingpage component:

```
<div className="wrapper">
 <div>{this.props.children}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of explicitly passing the components as `props` to `LandingPage` component, you can nest them inside the `LandingPage` component

```
<LandingPage {...props}>
   <SignInPage />
</LandingPage>
```

`SignIn` component will be passed to the `LandingPage` component as props and will be accessible using `props.children`

```
return (
  <div className="wrapper">
    {this.props.children}
  </div>
);
```

An advantage of this approach is that you can nest as many components inside `LandingPage` component and they all will be rendered inside `LandingPage` component using `this.props.children`

Your routes will look like this after this change

```
<Route path={ROUTES.LANDING} render={(props) => <LandingPage {...props}> <SignInPage/> </LandingPage> }/>
<Route path={ROUTES.SIGNIN} render={(props) => <LandingPage {...props}> <SignInPage/> </LandingPage>}/>
<Route path={ROUTES.REGISTER} render={(props) => <LandingPage {...props}> <RegisterPage/> </LandingPage>}/>
<Route render={(props) => <LandingPage {...props}> <SignInPage/> </LandingPage>}/>
```

Comment: Thank you.  That's helpful.  Is there a way to distinguish between children when rendering? Eg <div>{this.props.children.child1}> or something like that?

Comment: @Sharon `this.props.children` will be an array. You can access and render specific child elements using array indexes. First child element will be at `this.props.children[0]` and so on...